# How does data get added when there are multiple data files?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I create new database with 2 data files, then how does data get added to each file? Is it Round Robin, proportional or sequential?

Answer (score 3):

**From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15#file-and-filegroup-fill-strategy):**

> Filegroups use a proportional fill strategy across all the files within each filegroup. As data is written to the filegroup, the SQL Server Database Engine writes an amount proportional to the free space in the file to each file within the filegroup, instead of writing all the data to the first file until full. It then writes to the next file.
> For example, if file f1 has 100 MB free and file f2 has 200 MB free, one extent is given from file f1, two extents from file f2, and so on. In this way, both files become full at about the same time, and simple striping is achieved.

Comment: Is it valid question to ask - what if both the data files are not in any filegroup? Or there will always be 1 default file group with atleast 1 data file?